# How to speed up vector equations in Matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab, regression, matrix-multiplication

I'm using the following code to do logistic regression with stochastic gradient descent in Matlab. The total number of training + testing samples are about 600K. The code runs for hours. How can I speed it up?

```
%% load dataset

clc;
clear;
load('covtype.mat');

Data = [X y];

%% Split into testing and training data in a 1:9 split

nRows=size(Data,1);
randRows=randperm(nRows);  % generate random ordering of row indices
Test=Data(randRows(1:58101),:);  % index using random order
Train=Data(randRows(58102:end),:);

Testx=Test(:,1:54);
Testy=Test(:,55:end);

Trainx=Train(:,1:54);
Trainy=Train(:,55:end);

%% Perform stochastic gradient descent on training data

lambda=0.01; % regularisation constant
alpha=0.01; % step length constant

theta_old = zeros(54,1);
theta_new = theta_old;
z=1;

for count = 1:size(Train,1)
    theta_old = theta_new;
    theta_new = theta_old + (alpha*Trainy(count)* (1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(Trainy(count)*(Trainx(count,:)*theta_old)))).*Trainx(count,:))' - alpha*lambda*2*theta_old; %//'
    n = norm(theta_new);
    llr = lambda*n*n;
    count_dummy(z)=count; % dummy variable to store iteration number for plotting later
    % calculate log likelihood error for test data with current value of theta_new
    for i = 1:size(Test,1)
        llr = llr - 1.*log(1.0 + exp(-(Testy(i)*(Testx(i,:)*theta_new))));
    end
    llr_dummy(z)=llr; % dummy variable to store llr for plotting later
    z=z+1;

end
thetaopt = theta_new; % this is optimal theta


%% Plot results on testing data

plot(count_dummy, llr_dummy);
```

I have to calculate the log likelihood error of test data at every iteration to plot it. How can I speed up this code?

Comment: I would start by putting `tic/toc` on code sections and measure the average time each step takes. Also it would be a good idea to preallocate `count_dummy` and `llr_dummy` arrays instead of letting them grow inside the loop, causing many memory reallocations.

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro, how should I preallocate the two arrays? I am a beginner to Matlab. Also, is there a way to compute the llr variable (which currently requires an inner loop) in a single line? Perhaps there is a 'sum over all rows' type of function in Matlab that I don't know of?

Comment: Preallocation is easy. Take `count_dummy` for example. Every loop it grows one value, so Matlab have to reallocate the array in memory. As `z=z+1` and the loop goes from `1` to `size(Train,1)`, you just have to put this before the loop: `count_dummy = zeros(1, size(Train, 1));`. That preallocates the full array only one time. As for the `llr` variable, you could try vectorizing the expression by replacing all `i`'s with `1:size(Test,1)` and take out the `for/end` loop to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. I still don't understand how replacing the i's as you said would work, but I'll try it anyway.

Comment: I recommend you read this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

Comment: Instead of using `tic; toc`, you can use the [profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) to get more information about what's eating up your time.

Comment: Use the profiler to identify slow process and optimize from there.